# Python: cannot return a value assigned inside of a function outside of that function to later use

Tags: python

```
def program(n):
    name = input("What is your name? >")
    return name
print(name)
```

I have a code that i am trying to execute very similar to this. When executing it, it will not return the variable 'name' i used in the function in order to use that variable outside the function. Why is this?
  I am super new to coding by the way so please excuse me if i made a stupid mistake.

Comment: You need to call the function, ie:`print(program(n))`

Comment: You don't seem to have an understanding of what's called "scope." Not all variables are not global; they are not available everywhere. This is a *useful* feature.

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort. An introductory python tutorial (e.g. [Python Functions Tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/functions-python-3-basics-tutorial/), and [Python Functions Parameter Tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/function-parameters-python-3-basics/?completed=/functions-python-3-basics-tutorial/), etc) would've been found *easily*, if you had taken 5 minutes to search.

Answer (score 3):

When you run your program, you need to assign the result (i.e. whatever is `return`ed in your program, to another variable). Example:

```
def get_name():
    name = input('Name please! ')
    return name

name = get_name()
print('Hello ' + name)
```

<sup>Pssst.. I took your function parameter `n` away since it was *not* being used for anything. If you're using it inside your actual program, you should keep it :)</sup>

---

For a bit of a more in-depth explanation...

Variables that are declared inside your neat little function over there can't be seen once you come out of it (though there are some exceptions that we don't need to get into right now). If you're interested in how this works, it's known as "variable scope."

Comment: You removed the argument that is being taken in to the `program` function. Which is fine, but you should explain *why* you removed it.

Comment: Fixed "away since it was being used for anything" --> "...since it was *not* being used ..."

Comment: @ray Thanks! Didn't see that :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Np. BTW, given that we're trying to help OP, pointing out that calling a function "program" is a poor naming choice would be a good idea. The name `get_name` should be suggested instead.

Comment: @ray Yeah that's a good choice. Didn't think about that when writing this :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Need to be consistent: `name = get_name()` ... `print('Hello ' + name)` :)

Comment: @ray I really hope I'm not missing anything now... :P

Answer (score 2):

To execute the content of a function you need to make a call to the function and assign the return value to some variable. To fix your example, you would do:

```py
def get_name():
    name = input("What is your name? >")
    return name

name = get_name()
print(name)
```

I have changed the function name from `program()` to `get_name()` seeing as `program()` is a ambiguous name for a function.

This snippet will make a call to the `get_name()` function and assign the return value to the variable `name`. It is important to note, that the `name` variable inside the function is actually a different variable to the one that we are assigning to outside the function. *Note: I have removed the argument `n` from `get_name()` since it was not being used.*

Comment: You removed the argument that is being taken in to the `program` function. Which is fine, but you should explain *why* you removed it.

Comment: Given that we're trying to help OP, pointing out that calling a function "program" is a poor naming choice would be a good idea. The name `get_name` should be suggested instead.